# AngularJS Form Validation - Skipping pre-filled input field

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a page with one input field which takes the input and pre-fills it into a form in a Bootstrap Modal.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var modal = $(this);
        var recipient = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        modal.find('.companypostcode input').val(recipient);
    });
});
</script>
```

The form is validated using the same way shown in this tutorial: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

But once the rest of the form is filled in and submit is clicked, the validation marks the Postcode field as not being filled.

I can click the field and enter a space and it will work fine but I shouldn't have to do this.

process PHP checks for empty inputs as follows:

```
if (empty($_POST['name']))
  $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['CompanyName']))
  $errors['CompanyName'] = 'Company name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['PostCode']))
  $errors['PostCode'] = 'Company postcode is required.';

if (empty($_POST['EmailAddress']))
  $errors['EmailAddress'] = 'Email address is required.';

if (empty($_POST['TelephoneNumber']))
  $errors['TelephoneNumber'] = 'Telephone number is required.';
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you show your html ??

Comment: @Vanojx1 Here's the HTML: http://pastebin.com/jnvpn2Tc, PHP: http://pastebin.com/Pegysr4L

Comment: add this console.log(modal.find('.companypostcode input').val());  after this modal.find('.companypostcode input').val(recipient); and see what you get

Comment: @Vanojx1 The input from the first field correctly passes through to the field, it's just Angular isn't picking up on it, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh wait but if u use the same ng-model with your 2 different fields the data-binding will do the entire work for you.... give it a try

Comment: @Vanojx1still nothing unfortunately.

Comment: and if you change function formController($scope, $http) { with formApp.controller("formController",function($scope,$http){ stll nothing??

Answer (score 0):

If that form in Bootstrap modal uses AngularJs for validation, then you have to notify AngularJs that the model has changed. Otherwise you have only updated the value in input field, but not in the underlying model.

but without actual code to look at, this is just quessing

Most likely you will need to call `$scope.$apply()`

Like this

```
      <script>
      $(function(){
          $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
              var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
              var modal = $(this);
              var recipient = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
              modal.find('.companypostcode input').val(recipient);

              //TODO: Notify angularJs about changed value
              $scope.$apply();
          });
      });
      </script>
```